# How to join pairs of strings inside a list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list like

```
myl = ['A','B','C','D','E','F'] #length always even
```

Now my desired output is `'AB','CD','EF'`

I tried

```
>>> myl = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
>>> even_pos = myl[::2]
>>> odd_pos = myl[::-2]
>>> odd_pos.reverse()
>>> newlist = zip(even_pos,odd_pos)
>>> for x in newlist:
...     print "".join(list(x))
...
...
AB
CD
EF
>>>
```

I don't like this way because I think this is too much.

So, is there any better way to achieve my output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this concisely using a list comprehension or generator expression:

```
>>> myl = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
>>> [''.join(myl[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(myl), 2)]
['AB', 'CD', 'EF']
>>> print '\n'.join(''.join(myl[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(myl), 2))
AB
CD
EF
```

You could replace `''.join(myl[i:i+2])` with `myl[i] + myl[i+1]` for this particular case, but using the `''.join()` method is easier for when you want to do groups of three or more.

Or an alternative that comes from the documentation for [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> map(''.join, zip(*[iter(myl)]*2))
['AB', 'CD', 'EF']
```

Answer (score 3):

Why is your method so complicated? You could do basically what you did, but in one line, like so:

```
[ "".join(t) for t in zip(myl[::2], myl[1::2]) ]
```

F.J's answer is more efficient though.

Comment: His method is so complicated because he most likely doesn't know about list comprehensions, so I don't blame him.

Comment: @jdi: Yes I didn't know about `list comprehensions` and after seeing then `mind = blown`

Comment: @jdi: I'm actually talking about taking `myl[::-2]` and reversing it in order to get the odd positions..

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
>>> ["%s%s" % (myl[c], myl[c+1]) for c in range(0, 6, 2)]
['AB', 'CD', 'EF']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably write:

```
[myl[i] + myl[i + 1] for i in xrange(len(myl), step=2)]
```

Comment: I would avoid string concatenation by adding them together. Use join or string formatting. Also, because of the explicit x+1 index, this will break if the size of the list is not even.

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to avoid string concatenation with `+` when you're only adding two strings. It's not going to result in quadratic behavior, and might even be a bit faster. And the OP guaranteed that the length is even.

Comment: But he didn't guarantee that the size of the list couldn't be 10k. String concatenation using + is slow. Even Guido says to avoid it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
myl = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
[''.join(myl[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(myl), 2)]
print '\n'.join(''.join(myl[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(myl), 2))
```