# Python - making a function that would add "-" between letters

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function, `f(x)`, that would add a `"-"` between each letter:

For example:

```
f("James")
```

should output as:

```
J-a-m-e-s-
```

I would love it if you could use simple python functions as I am new to programming. Thanks in advance. Also, please use the "for" function because it is what I'm trying to learn.

Edit:

yes, I do want the `"-"` after the `"s"`.

Comment: why there is `-` after `s`?

Comment: You mean this `'-'.join("James")` ?

Comment: Please add that as an answer so that I can upvote it.

Comment: Why did I get a down vote though?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 posted it as a comment because i don't know what exactly that op wants.

Comment: @James what's the answer for my first comment?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I do want the "-" after the "s"

Comment: James @spam answer is best (in my view)  even if you want suffix `-` after `s` then add it explicitly as commented their

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Also, please use the "for" function because it is what I'm trying to learn

```
>>> def f(s):
        m = s[0]
        for i in s[1:]:
             m += '-' + i
        return m

>>> f("James")
'J-a-m-e-s'
```

- `m = s[0]` character at the index 0 is assigned to the variable `m`
- `for i in s[1:]:` iterate from the second character and
- `m += '-' + i` append `-` + char to the variable `m`
- Finally return the value of variable  `m`

If you want `-` at the last then you could do like this.

```
>>> def f(s):
        m = ""
        for i in s:
            m +=  i + '-'
        return m

>>> f("James")
'J-a-m-e-s-'
```

Comment: "Because it is what **I'm trying to learn**," --- if someone trying to learn then posting an unexplained code is not that much helpful. You should tell why your code is not bad in Python -- (don't suggest C kindof code in Python)

Comment: Avinash every code in computer runs in 0s and 1s form, how much internal you would like to tech him? I was just telling some obvious explanation this question and python. check  @sapam's answer.

Comment: anyways, your answer is good because OP specially request for "for" loop code.

Comment: unnecessary to pop off the first list item because the OP wants a final -, so `for i in s: m += i + '-'` would achieve this. Though I'm not a great fan of string concatenation, strings are immutable so this can be expensive.

Answer (score 8):

Can I try like this:

```
>>> def f(n):
...     return '-'.join(n)
...
>>> f('james')
'j-a-m-e-s'
>>>
```

Not really sure if you require the last 'hyphen'.

Edit:

Even if you want suffixed `'-'`, then can do like

```
def f(n):
   return '-'.join(n) + '-'
```

As being learner, it is important to understand for your that ["better to concat more than two strings in python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043636/any-reason-not-to-use-to-concatenate-two-strings) would be using [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), whereas `+` operator is fine to append one string with another.

Please read following posts to explore further:

- [Any reason not to use + to concatenate two strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043636/any-reason-not-to-use-to-concatenate-two-strings)
- [which is better to concat  string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-better-to-concat-a-string-in-python)
- [How slow is Python's string concatenation vs. str.join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055477/how-slow-is-pythons-string-concatenation-vs-str-join)

Comment: I like your post as first post and added few more details as I notice OP is new, please check updated answer, if don't like then edit/revert. good luck.

Comment: As of Python 2.6 (I think) it is actually faster to use ```+=``` then to use ```str.join()```. Sorry I forget the source, but feel free to ```timeit``` yourself.

Comment: @pzp1997 yes to add two strings `+=` would be better than `str.join` : check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169839/which-is-better-to-concat-a-string-in-python

Comment: That was actually the source that I was referring to. And according to that ```+=``` is faster than ```str.join()``` in EVERY case. Even when concatenating  100,000 one hundred character strings += is faster (and I doubt anyone would ever reasonably need to do something that extreme). Part of the reason might be because it takes more time to resolve ```str.join()``` than ```+=```, which is an operator.

Comment: Then Pep8 needs to be updated: `Code should be written in a way that does not disadvantage other implementations of Python [snip]. For example, do not rely on CPython's efficient implementation of in-place string concatenation for statements in the form a += b or a = a + b. [snip] In performance sensitive parts of the library, the ''.join() form should be used instead.`

Answer (score 2):

```
text_list = [c+"-" for c in text]
text_strung = "".join(text_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you asked for a solution that uses `for` and a final `-`, simply iterate over the message and add the character and '-' to an intermediate list, then `join` it up. This avoids the use of string concatenations:

```
>>> def f(message)
        l = []
        for c in message:
            l.append(c)
            l.append('-')
        return "".join(l)
>>> print(f('James'))
J-a-m-e-s-
```

Answer (score 1):

As a function, takes a string as input.

```
def dashify(input):
    output = ""
    for ch in input:
        output = output + ch + "-"
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I just have to take [Alexander Ravikovich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382307/236195) a step further:

```
f = lambda text: "".join([c+"-" for c in text])

print(f('James'))  # J-a-m-e-s-
```

It is *never* too early to [learn about list comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

`"".join(a_list)` is self-explanatory: glueing elements of a list together with a string (empty string in this example).

`lambda`... well that's just a way to define a function in a line. Think

```
square = lambda x: x**2
square(2)  # returns 4
square(3)  # returns 9
```

Python is fun, it's not {enter-a-boring-programming-language-here}.