# What is the advantage of collecting into a list and joining?

Tags: python

It is common practice to not use concatenation for strings/bytes/etc. in python, but to collect into a list and then `''.join()` it. So instead of this:

```
str = 'This is' + ' ' + 'a '
str += 'long ' + 'st' + 'ring' + '.'
str += ' blah'
str += ' blah'
str += ' blah'
```

I would do this:

```
l = ['This is', ' ', 'a ']
l += ['long ', 'st', 'ring', '.']
l.append(' blah')
l.append(' blah')
l.append(' blah')
str = ''.join(l)
```

The idea being to not need to realocate the string with each new piece.

How does this help? Now the list needs to get realocated (to hold more items) with each `append()`?

Comment: Did you mean the `l =` line to be `str =`?

Comment: Would you rather append to a list or make copies of a string? Strings in python are immutable, so `+=` copies the old one and adds on a new string, while assigning to the old reference

Comment: @RoryDaulton fixed. Thanks

Comment: Try benchmarking first, then look for an explanation for the results

Comment: When you append list, python just allocate memory for a new element and change pointers in a list to reach this new element. But string are copping, except short which is a constant.

Comment: @StanleyR A list in python (at least is CPython) AFAIK is an array, not a linked list

Comment: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-list-implementation/

Comment: Closed as dupe because the answer there by Lennart Regebro has measurements and explains why old-timers who used Python pre-2.3 developed this habit and continue to propagate it. Everything you need to know about this question is there.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043636/any-reason-not-to-use-to-concatenate-two-strings

Comment: before joining the items from a list, if you want to perform some operations supported by list data structure then join by list make sense.