# Printing int and float in Python

Tags: python, printing, conceptual

Considering the example below, why would anyone choose the first print instead of the second?

```
def main():
    name = input("Input your name:")
    age = int(input("Input you age:"))

    print("Your name is " + name + " and you are " + str(age) + " years old.")
    print("Your name is", name, "and you are" , age, "years old.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It seems to me that `print("text", var, "text")` is more straightforward, since there's no need to explicitly convert our `int` to `str`.

Are there any relevant use cases for the `print("text"+str(var)+"text")` format?

Comment: `+` generically concatenates strings. Of course you want to be able to concatenate strings. There are way better options to output numbers in strings, but turning the number into a string and concatenating it is an option which simply exists because type casting and concatenation exists. No, it's in no way better and  should probably never be your go-to, but there it is.

Comment: I think that there are no advantages between the two methods, its just a matter of taste and the kind of print you are doing.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043636/any-reason-not-to-use-to-concatenate-two-strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way of doing this is [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting) like:

```py
print(f"Your name is {name} and you are {age} years old.")
```

> Considering the example below, why would anyone choose the first print instead of the second?

Well, the first way (concatenation of strings and expressions converted to strings) is obsolete and unusable for me, since we have proper formatting (like my example above). We can construct any string we want straightforwardly and clearly.

If we apply the same logic to `*args` approach, as for me, the outcome is the same.